# Ansible test for variable use another is not defined

Tags: ansible

I use the ternary operator to return a variable if it is defined, otherwise another one:

```
 {{ (variable1 is defined) | ternary(variable1, variable2) }}
```

It's a bit clumsy. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
- hosts: nodes
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    var1: value1

  tasks:

  - name: Show 1
    debug: msg="{{ var1 | default('AAAAAA') }}"

  - name: Show 2
    debug: msg="{{ var2 | default('BBBBBB') }}"
```